# PostgreSQL query against millions of rows takes long on UUIDs

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a reference table for UUIDs that is roughly 200M rows.  I have ~5000 UUIDs that I want to look up in the reference table.  Reference table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE object_store AS (
    project_id UUID,
    object_id UUID,
    object_name VARCHAR(20),
    description VARCHAR(80)
);

CREATE INDEX object_store_project_idx ON object_store(project_id);
CREATE INDEX object_store_id_idx ON object_store(object_id);
```

#### *** Edit #2 ***

Request for the temp_objects table definition.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_objects AS (
    object_id UUID
)
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

The reason for the separate index is because `object_id` is not unique, and can belong to many different projects.  The reference table is just a temp table of UUIDs (temp_objects) that I want to check (5000 object_ids).

If I query the above reference table with 1 object_id literal value, it's almost instantaneous (2ms).  If the temp table only has 1 row, again, instantaneous (2ms).  But with 5000 rows it takes 25 minutes to even return.  Granted it pulls back >3M rows of matches.

#### *** Edited ***

**This is for 1 row comparison (4.198 ms):**

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, FORMAT TEXT)SELECT O.project_id
FROM temp_objects T JOIN object_store O ON T.object_id = O.object_id;
                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..475780.22 rows=494005 width=65) (actual time=0.038..2.631 rows=1194 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=1202, local hit=1
   ->  Seq Scan on temp_objects t  (cost=0.00..13.60 rows=360 width=16) (actual time=0.007..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)
         Buffers: local hit=1
   ->  Index Scan using object_store_id_idx on object_store l  (cost=0.57..1307.85 rows=1372 width=81) (actual time=0.027..1.707 rows=1194 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (object_id = t.object_id)
         Buffers: shared hit=1202
 Planning time: 0.173 ms
 Execution time: 3.096 ms
(9 rows)

Time: 4.198 ms
```

**This is for 4911 row comparison (1579082.974 ms (26:19.083)):**

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, FORMAT TEXT)SELECT O.project_id
FROM temp_objects T JOIN object_store O ON T.object_id = O.object_id;
                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..3217316.86 rows=3507438 width=65) (actual time=0.041..1576913.100 rows=8043500 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=5185078 read=2887548, local hit=71
   ->  Seq Scan on temp_objects d  (cost=0.00..96.56 rows=2556 width=16) (actual time=0.009..3.945 rows=4911 loops=1)
         Buffers: local hit=71
   ->  Index Scan using object_store_id_idx on object_store l  (cost=0.57..1244.97 rows=1372 width=81) (actual time=1.492..320.081 rows=1638 loops=4911)
         Index Cond: (object_id = t.object_id)
         Buffers: shared hit=5185078 read=2887548
 Planning time: 0.169 ms
 Execution time: 1579078.811 ms
(9 rows)

Time: 1579082.974 ms (26:19.083)
```

Eventually I want to group and get a count of the matching object_ids by project_id, using standard grouping.  The aggregate is at the upper end (of course) of the cost.  It took just about 25 minutes again to complete the below query.  Yet, when I limit the temp table to only 1 row, it comes back in 21ms.  Something is not adding up...

```
EXPLAIN SELECT O.project_id, count(*)
FROM temp_objects T JOIN object_store O ON T.object_id = O.object_id GROUP BY O.project_id;
                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=6189484.10..6189682.84 rows=19874 width=73)
   Group Key: o.project_id
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..6155795.69 rows=6737683 width=65)
         ->  Seq Scan on temp_objects t  (cost=0.00..120.10 rows=4910 width=16)
         ->  Index Scan using object_store_id_idx on object_store o  (cost=0.57..1239.98 rows=1372 width=81)
               Index Cond: (object_id = t.object_id)
(6 rows)
```

I'm on PostgreSQL 10.6, running 2 CPUs and 8GB of RAM on an SSD.  I have ANALYZEd the tables, I have set the `work_mem` to 50MB, `shared_buffers` to 2GB, and have set the `random_page_cost` to 1.  All helped the queries actually to come back in several minutes, but still not as fast as I feel it should be.

I have the option to go to cloud computing if CPUs/RAM/parallelization make a big difference.  Just looking for suggestions on how to get this simple query to return in < few seconds (if possible).

#### *** UPDATE ***

Taking the hint from Jürgen Zornig, I changed both `object_id` fields to be `bigint`, using just the top half of the UUID and reducing my datasize by half.  Doing the aggregate query above the query now performs at ~16min.

Next, taking jjane's suggestion of `set enable_nestloop to off`, my aggregate query jumped to 6min!  Unfortunately, all the other suggestions haven't sped it up past 6min, although it's interesting that changing my "TEMPORARY" table to a permanent one allowed 2 workers to work it, it didn't change the time.  I think jjane is accurate by saying the IO is the binding factor here.  Here is the latest explain plan from the 6min (wish it were faster, still, but it's better!):

```
explain (analyze, buffers, format text) select project_id, count(*) from object_store natural join temp_object group by project_id;
                                                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=3966899.86..3967396.69 rows=19873 width=73) (actual time=368124.126..368744.157 rows=153633 loops=1)
   Group Key: object_store.project_id
   Buffers: shared hit=243022 read=2423215, temp read=3674 written=3687
   I/O Timings: read=870720.440
   ->  Sort  (cost=3966899.86..3966999.23 rows=39746 width=73) (actual time=368124.116..368586.497 rows=333427 loops=1)
         Sort Key: object_store.project_id
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 29392kB
         Buffers: shared hit=243022 read=2423215, temp read=3674 written=3687
         I/O Timings: read=870720.440
         ->  Gather  (cost=3959690.23..3963863.56 rows=39746 width=73) (actual time=366476.369..366827.313 rows=333427 loops=1)
               Workers Planned: 2
               Workers Launched: 2
               Buffers: shared hit=243022 read=2423215
               I/O Timings: read=870720.440
               ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=3958690.23..3958888.96 rows=19873 width=73) (actual time=366472.712..366568.313 rows=111142 loops=3)
                     Group Key: object_store.project_id
                     Buffers: shared hit=243022 read=2423215
                     I/O Timings: read=870720.440
                     ->  Hash Join  (cost=132.50..3944473.09 rows=2843429 width=65) (actual time=7.880..363848.830 rows=2681167 loops=3)
                           Hash Cond: (object_store.object_id = temp_object.object_id)
                           Buffers: shared hit=243022 read=2423215
                           I/O Timings: read=870720.440
                           ->  Parallel Seq Scan on object_store  (cost=0.00..3499320.53 rows=83317153 width=73) (actual time=0.467..324932.880 rows=66653718 loops=3)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=242934 read=2423215
                                 I/O Timings: read=870720.440
                           ->  Hash  (cost=71.11..71.11 rows=4911 width=8) (actual time=7.349..7.349 rows=4911 loops=3)
                                 Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 256kB
                                 Buffers: shared hit=66
                                 ->  Seq Scan on temp_object  (cost=0.00..71.11 rows=4911 width=8) (actual time=0.014..2.101 rows=4911 loops=3)
                                       Buffers: shared hit=66
 Planning time: 0.247 ms
 Execution time: 368779.757 ms
(32 rows)

Time: 368780.532 ms (06:08.781)
```

So I'm at 6min per query now.  I think with I/O costs, I may try for an in-memory store on this table if possible to see if getting it off SSD makes it even better.

Comment: Edited for execution plan details requested (only on the straight query)

Comment: There are **two** tables in your query. You only show the definition for **one** table(plus its index) How could we possibly answer this question?

Comment: There you go joop.

Comment: So you dont have any primary keys, nor foreign keys, nor supporting indexes for the FKs. Do you want the DBMS to *guess* your intention and *invent* keys/indexes by itself?

Comment: Maybe I haven't made it clear, sorry.  I *do* have supporting indexes on the individual columns, however the object_ids are not PK/FK relationships.  They are two independent collections.  I'm looking for the intersection.  The temp_objects.object_id and object_store.object_id are independent of each other, and aren't implying any superset conditions.  I'd be open to any refactoring suggestions, as I thought that this would possibly be the fastest way to determine the intersection between two collections (one 200M, one 5000).

Comment: So you don't have a PK. Is the combination of {project_id
    object_id } UNIQUE? Is there some other column in your table that would make it unique? If not, your table could contain duplicates, and is factually meaningless.

Comment: Good observation, wildplasser.  The loading process ensures {project_id, object_id} is unique, but I did not include that as PK or UNIQUE on the table trying to keep the load and usage as fast as possible.  The table is static, read-only once populated, so no need to enforce uniqueness.  However, if specifying that to the DB makes it faster, I would absolutely do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UUIDs are (*EDIT*) *working against adaptive cache management and, because of their random nature effectively dropping the cache hit ratio because the index space is larger than memory.* Ids cover a numerically wide range equally distributed, so in fact every Id lands pretty much on its own leaf on the index tree. As the index leaf determines in which data page the row is saved in disk pretty much every row gets its own page resulting in a whole lot of extremely expensive I/O Operations to get all these rows read in.

That's the reason why its generally not recommended to use UUIDs and if you really need UUIDs then at least generate timestamp/mac-prefixed UUIDs (have a look at `uuid_generate_v1()` -  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/uuid-ossp.html) that are numerically close to each other, therefore chances are higher that data rows are clustered together on lesser data Pages resulting in fewer I/O Operations to get more Data in.

Long Story Short: Randomness over a large range kills your index (*well actually not the index, it results in a lot of expensive I/O to get data on reading and to maintain the index on writing*) and therefore slows queries down to a point where it is as good as having no index at all.

Here is also an [article](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/sequential-uuid-generators/) for reference

Comment: Interesting. So further question is that I want to track my unique objects, but with only 200M, you're saying UUID is overkill? If I use a timestamp UUID and the top ~16bytes are all the same, the index will perform (many factors) better?

Comment: Yes, definitely. By using random Indizes, you are completely bypassing any caching mechanisms

Comment: They aren't the "worst" thing you can index.  They are really just integers.  Comparisons and sorting are very quick.  (unlike, say, random utf-8 strings).  the problem here is the randomness of the data distribution and how slow the index scan turns out to be, which could be mostly an I/O bottleneck if it is getting paged out.

Comment: Using an UUID as a FK is twice as bad, because the supporting index for the FK will have the same problem. Instead, create a surrogate key (serial) and use that for the PK<-FK. The uuid could have *one* UNIQUE constraint on the table where it lives. In short: avoid *fat* keys, except as a UNIQUE constraint on the *domain* table, where it will function as the natural/candidate key.

Comment: @rotten Edited my answer to replace my subjective writing with a more precise disadvantage of indexing random UUIDs. Hope its clearer now

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the centerpiece of your question is why it doesn't scale up from one input row to 5000 input rows linearly.  But I think that this is a red herring.  How are you choosing the one row?  If you choose the same one row each time, then the data will stay in cache and will be very fast.  I bet this is what you are doing.  If you choose a different random one row each time you do a one-row plan, you will probably find the scaling to be more linear.

You should turn on track_io_timing.  I have little doubt that IO is actually the bottleneck, but it is always nice to see it actually measured and reported, I have been surprised before.

The use of temporary table will inhibit parallel query.  You might want to test with a permanent table, to see if you do get use of parallel workers, and if so, whether that actually helps.  If you do this test, you should use your aggregation version of the query.  They parallelize more efficiently than non-aggregation queries do, and if that is your ultimate goal that is what you should initially test with.

Another thing you could try is a large setting of `effective_io_concurrency`. But, that will only help if your plan uses bitmap scans to start with, which the plans you show do not. Setting random_page_cost from 1 to a slightly higher value might encourage it to use bitmap scans.  (`effective_io_concurrency` is weird because bitmap plans can get a substantial realistic benefit from a higher setting, but the planner doesn't give bitmap plans any credit for that benefit they receive. So you must be "accidentally" using that plan already in order to get the benefit)

At some point (as you increase the number of rows in temp_objects) it is going to be faster to hash that table, and hashjoin it to a seq-scan of the object_store table. Is 5000 already past the point at which that would be faster? The planner clearly doesn't think so, but the planner never gets the cut-over point exactly right, and is often off by quite a bit.  What happens if you `set enable_nestloop TO off;` before running your query?

Have you done low-level benchmarking of your SSD (outside of the database)?  Assuming substantially all of your time is spent on IO reads and nearly none of those are fulfilled by the filesystem cache, you are getting 1576913/2887548 = 0.55ms per read. That seems pretty long.  That is about what I get on a bottom-dollar laptop where the SSD is being exposed through a VM layer.  I'd expect better than that from server-grade hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  The instance is hosted in AWS RDS, so I'm sure there's more money that can be thrown at better I/O...

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you have also a proper index  for temp_objects table

```
CREATE INDEX temp_object_id_idx ON temp_objects(object_id);

SELECT O.project_id
FROM temp_objects T 
JOIN object_store O ON T.object_id = O.object_id;
```

Comment: For the record, tried this and it did not affect the EXPLAIN plan at all :/

Comment: It probably doesn't hurt, but with 5,000 rows in the temp table, it isn't going to make a huge difference either.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly:  I would try to get the index into memory.  What is shared_buffers set to?  If it is small, lets make that bigger first.  See if we can reduce the index scan IO.

Next:  Are parallel queries enabled?  I'm not sure that will help here very much because you have only 2 cpus, but it wouldn't hurt.

Even though the object column is completely random, I'd also bump up the statistics on that table from the default (100 rows or something like that) to a few thousand rows.  Then run Analyze again.   (or for thoroughness, `vacuum analyze`)

Work Mem at 50M may be low too.  It could potentially be larger if you don't have a lot of concurrent users and you have G's of RAM to work with.  Too large and it can be counter productive, but you could go up a bit more to see if it helps.

You could try CTAS on the big table into a new table to sort object id so that it isn't completely random.

There might be a crazy partitioning scheme you could come up with if you were using PostgreSQL 12 that would group the object ids into some even partition distribution.